# (Spring RestTemplate) How to elegantly handle retry logic with exception handling and null checking?

Tags: java, spring

I have a utility class which is making all of my REST calls. I want the class to do as much exception handling as it can - if possible, I want it to 100% guarantee a valid response to the calling class.

The issue is that in order to implement retry logic I am making the call in a while loop with a counter. This means I have to return inside the while loop.

The code I have now I think is overkill. Is it okay to simply return the valid response inside the loop and throw an exception after it, since at that point something should have gone wrong?

The context is that this is a shared library for our internal apps to access secured data like DB credentials, so this really needs to be as bulletproof as possible. That is why my code now is overkill.

```
  private int makeVaultRenewCall(String url, String token) {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.set(vaultTokenHeaderString, token);    // set token header
            HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
            VaultRenewResponse response = null;
            int retryCounter = 0;
            while (retryCounter < 4) {
                try {
                    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
                    response = vaultMapper.mapRenewResponse(responseEntity.getBody());
                    return (int)response.getAuth().getLease_duration();
                } catch (HttpServerErrorException e) {
                    retryCounter++;
                    if (retryCounter == 3) {
                        if(url.equals(vaultSecretRenewURL)) {
                            throw new THDVaultAccessException(secretRefreshErrorMsg, e);
                        } else throw new THDVaultAccessException(authRefreshErrorMsg, e);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!(null != response && null != response.getAuth() && 0 != response.getAuth().getLease_duration())) {
                if(url.equals(vaultSecretRenewURL)) {
                    throw new THDVaultAccessException(secretRefreshErrorMsg);
                } else throw new THDVaultAccessException(authRefreshErrorMsg);
            }
            return (int)response.getAuth().getLease_duration();
```